# New Office Formats (*.xlsx, *.docx etc.) and SharePoint Metadata Promotion

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-integration

we are seeing the following behavior in our SharePoint 2013 on-premise. Repro steps below:

1) Create a document library with versioning (major and minor versions turned on, require checkout)

2) Upload a random docx, xlsx etc. Document with at least one Metadata field filled out (e.g. Title or any other custom value). For simplicity I will call it [DocProperty1] = "Bla" - Version 0.1 is created in SharePoint

3) Publish this document (Version 1.0)

4) Check out the existing document, modify it offline, then check the new version in - do not override but add as a new Version - V. 1.1

5) The Edit Form that appears after uploading will show [DocProperty1] = empty - same goes for any other metadata that was previously there

Try the same behavior with .xls or .doc files (old format) and it works - the metadata is preserverd so that at step 5 [DocProperty1] = "Bla"

This is obviously a bug, is there a fix to this or do we have to "live with the workaround" of using old formats? Or is there a way to still get the advantages of sharepoint columns added to office documents with the new formats?

Thanks in advance, R